# Is there a way of using a shortcut to jump to the next text box?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

For example, I have multiple text boxes on a document, and instead of using the arrow keys to navigate downwards (or the mouse to manually click into the next text box), is it possible for me to use a keyboard shortcut to do this instead? Any input or workarounds (including macros) is appreciated.

Comment: People use the term "Text Box" to refer to different structures in Word. MS uses it to mean a graphical box that can hold text, as in Insert > Text Box. Many people use the term to refer to one of the ways to get people to add text at a location. Can you clarify what you mean? See my answer below addressing three possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If by "Text Box" you mean a **plain text Content Control**, select all the text and add a Group Content Control.

[image: screenshot]

- [Content Controls in Microsoft Word](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Create a Form Using Word Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_fillin_form.html) by Greg Maxey

If by "Text Box" you mean a **legacy Form Field**, you need to protect/lock at least that section of the document for filling in forms.

[image]

- [Making Forms with Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/forms.htm) (my page)

If by "Text Box" you mean a graphic text box or shape, there is no shortcut key built in to do this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See also for assigning your own shortcuts: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the tag you're using Microsoft Word, you can find any shortcuts [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_tableswin). For navigating tables they are all follows:

**Tab key** Move to the next cell in the row and select its content.

**Shift+Tab** Move to the previous cell in the row and select its content.

**Alt+Home** Move to the first cell in the row.

**Alt+End** Move to the last cell in the row.

**Alt+Page up** Move to the first cell in the column.

**Alt+Page down** Move to the last cell in the column.

**Up arrow key** Move to the previous row.

**Down arrow key** Move to the next row.

**Alt+Shift+Up arrow key** Move one row up.

**Alt+Shift+Down arrow key** Move one row down.